# Echoing selected on a loop with serialise and printf

Tags: php

for display hours how can i echo or print selected, the variable is `$value['hour']`, sorry i never used %1$s-%2$s before.

```
    <?php $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 86400; $i += 1800) {  
// 1800 = half hour, 86400 = one day
    printf('<option value="%1$s-%2$s" >%1$s-%2$s</option>',
           date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
}  ?>
```

I tried something like

```
   <?php $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 86400; $i += 1800) {  
// 1800 = half hour, 86400 = one day
    if($value['hour'] == "%1$s-%2$s" ){ $selected = "selected" ;}else {$selected= "";}
    printf('<option value="%1$s-%2$s" '.$selected.'>%1$s-%2$s</option>',
           date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
}  ?>
```

But is not working either. Any ideas pls.

Comment: what you want to display?

Comment: wich option is selected, i cant make a easy "if "because i tried with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the way i got it

```
<?php $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 86400; $i += 1800) {  
// 1800 = half hour, 86400 = one day
    $var = sprintf('%1$s-%2$s',date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
    if($value['hour'] == $var ){ $selected = "selected" ;}else {$selected= "";}
    printf('<option value="%1$s-%2$s" %3$s>%1$s-%2$s %3$s</option>',
           date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800), $selected);
}  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to get the value of the selected option with your PHP script, but PHP doesn't work the way you're trying to use it. The PHP script is executed on the server when the client navigates to a PHP file. When the PHP is done executing, the resulting HTML is sent to the client's browser. Any interaction the client has with that HTML will not be accessible to the PHP script that generated it because that script is no longer executing. If you simply want to display the value of the selected option elsewhere on the page, you can use JavaScript. If you want to send the value back to the server, you should use another PHP file for your form action.

Comment: Thanks for info i solve it pasing printf to a var then into the format, works great :) .

Comment: What does it do? I guess I didn't correctly figure out what you wanted.